# WordPress. Как сделать, чтобы из админки можно было добавить только один тег к посту?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно установить лимит на добавление тегов к посту. В конкретном случае, чтобы можно было добавить только один тег.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я смотрю вы любите один тэг, даже здесь он один. :) А если серьёзно, есть удобный плагин
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-limit-tags/